# C++: does the order in a function body matter

Tags: c++, class

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A{
public:
   int data[3];
private:
   int cnt;
public:
   void put(int v){data[cnt++]=v;}
   int take(){int c=cnt;cnt=0;return c;}
};

int main() {
    A a;
    a.take();
    a.put(a.take());
    a.put(1);
    cout<<a.data[0];
    return 0;


}
```

I understand most of this code, but I got confused by the function a.take(). In the main function, we firstly create an object a. Then we run a.take(). In this function, we first let c = cnt and then cnt is assigned a value of 0.

Why isn't there an error when c is assigned the value of cnt which has not have a  value yet.

It is total understandable for me if this function is written as 
    int take(){cnt=0;c = cnt;return c;}

Comment: *It is total understandable for me..."* - not me. your alternative could be reduced to simply `return (cnt = 0);` The variable `c` becomes worthless. Regardless, you're correct. `cnt` is indeterminate when `a.take` is invoked before `cnt` is ever intitialised. The result is an indeterminate `c`, and therefore undefined behavior.

Answer (score 2):

The author of this code is of the belief that using the initial call to `take()` to establish the `cnt` member value of `0` is standard-compliant; they're wrong (at least through C++14, I've not checked C++17)

Per the standard,

> 8.5 Initializers [dcl.init]
>
> 12. If no initializer is specified for an object, the object is default-initialized. When storage for an object with automatic or
>       dynamic storage duration is obtained, the object has an indeterminate
>       value, and if no initialization is performed for the object, that
>       object retains an indeterminate value until that value is replaced
>       (5.18). [Note: Objects with static or thread storage duration are
>       zero-initialized, see 3.6.2. — end note ] **If an indeterminate value is
>       produced by an evaluation, the behavior is undefined** except in the
>       following cases:

None of the exceptions apply to you, so I didn't bother showing them, but you can look them up for confirmation.

The proper way to do this is to establish a determine value for `cnt` before first use (such as a member initialization list), at which point the worthless `take()` call can then be removed. In other words,

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A{
public:
    int data[3];
private:
    int cnt;
public:
    A() : cnt(0) {} // HERE
    void put(int v){data[cnt++]=v;}
    int take(){int c=cnt;cnt=0;return c;}
};

int main()
{
    A a;
    a.put(a.take());
    a.put(1);
    cout<<a.data[0];
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's walk through `main()`:

1. `A a;`

At this step, you created an object `a` of type `A`.

What is in `a`?

(1) a public data member called `data`, which is an array of `int`.

(2) a private data member called `cnt`, which is an `int`.

**Note that at this step, the object `a` already has these two data members.**

**What their values are is another matter.**

(3) public function members `take()` and `put()`.

2. `a.take()`

Now you have created `a`, you can use it.

`a.take()` calls the public member function of `take()` of `a`.

In the body of `take()`

```
int c=cnt;cnt=0;return c;
```

`c` is initialzed with the value of the private data member `cnt` of `a`, before it is returned.

So it boils down to the question: What is the value of `cnt` at this point?

Your question:

> Why isn't there an error when c is assigned the value of cnt which has not have a value yet.

Your wording is not accurate. `cnt` does have a value. This value is undefined, however, in this case. That is, it could be anything. It could be 0, or 42, or -123.

The details:

1. Since you do not provide a default constructor `A()` for class `A`, the compiler would generate a synthesized default constructor for `A`, which is used to construct `a`.
2. Since you do not provide an in-class initializer for `cnt` (like `int cnt = 0;`), the default constructor will default initialize `cnt`.
3. Since `cnt` is an `int`, which is a built-in type, the default initialization rule for a built-in type says,  *variables of built-in type defined inside a function are uninitialized. The value of an uninitialized variable of built-in type is undefined.*
4. Since `a` is defined in function `main()`, `cnt` has an undefined value.

Answer (score 0):

As `cnt` is a member variable (non-global), it's value is un-initialized, which means it could be whatever was in that memory location before.  It's not an error to use it but the value it will read is effectively garbage.

As a side note, global and static variables are initialized to `0`.

Comment: I'd say it's not a *compile-time* error to use it, but it's definitely a programming/logic error since it invokes undefined behavior and therefore the program cannot be relied upon to behave in any particular way.